# Best practices for asking Facebook Permissions form GWT?

Tags: gwt, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I have used gwt-fb and invoked gb:ui method, Problem is facebook needs a redirect_uri and i do not want to redirect users form the page, IS there anyways i can get the Access_token into a callback method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most third-party authentication systems requires a redirect for security purposes. They usually include an [X-Frame-Options: DENY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/the_x-frame-options_response_header) header on their authentication page, so browsers won't let you show the permissions page in an iframe. So you'll have to live with full-page redirects.

Comment: You are right, more i thought about it it made sense.Thank you!